# read SQL and store value as variable on excel VBA.[ Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005) ]

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, runtime-error

i'm pretty new to sql and coding.
 

I want to read data from SQL and store it as variable on VBA to update cells in excel sheets, but when I run VBA, i encounter [Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)] from "rst.Open ssql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText"
 Please review my codes below. Thank you!

[this is sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIWqF.png)

```
Sub sql_po_stackflow()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String

strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=CINDY\MSSQLSERVER01;INITIAL CATALOG=mason01;"
strConn = strConn & "INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

cn.Open strConn

Dim r, c, endcol As Long
Dim LastRow, LastColumn As Long
Dim loc As Worksheet
Set loc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Backend")

With loc
  LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
End With

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ssql, gd, itn As String


    r = 161
    c = 14
    endcol = 21

    Do While (c < endcol + 1)
        Do While (r < LastRow + 1)


        itn = "XXX-XXX-XXX"
        ssql = "Select PONUMBER from po_east where ITEMNO = " & itn & ""

        rst.Open ssql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText

        gd = rst!PONUMBER.Value
        rst.Close

        loc.Range(loc.Cells(r, c), loc.Cells(r, c)) = gd

        rst.Close

        r = r + 176

        Loop

    r = 161
    c = c + 1

    Loop

cn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing single quotes around `itn` in your SQL

Comment: wow... i really appreciate your help, Tim!!!!!!! now it works T_T.